# How to detect a USB modem after restarting macOS Big Sur

Tags: objective-c, macos, usb, modem, macos-big-sur

TL;DR: After a restart of Big Sur, a System Report sees the USB modem (S/N 12345678), but /dev/cu.usbmodem123456781 does not exist until the modem is unplugged and plugged back in.

I'm using a USB modem (macOS) with a chipset made by Conexant.
With Mojave, my application worked fine -- always found the USB modem using this code:

```
    ORSSerialPortManager *serialPortManager = [ORSSerialPortManager sharedSerialPortManager];
    NSArray *availablePorts = serialPortManager.availablePorts;
    //  usbmodem123456781,
    //  "Bluetooth-Incoming-Port",
    //  URT1
    NSString *modemPath = nil;
    for ( ORSSerialPort *aPort in availablePorts ) {
        NSLog(@"aPort.description %@",aPort.description);
        if ( [aPort.description hasPrefix:@"usbmodem"] ) {
            // the modem has been found, the path is:
            // "/dev/cu.usbmodem123456781"
        }
    }
```

However, with Big Sur (I skipped Catalina), the modem is not detected after a restart.  Immediately after a restart, availablePorts is just this (usbmodem123456781 is missing):

```
 // "Bluetooth-Incoming-Port",
 // URT1
```

But, if I plug the modem in **after** the restart
(by unplugging and plugging back in), the modem is found.
Thus, macOS Big Sur only recognizes the modem if it is (re)connected **after** a restart.

ls -lt shows this after a restart and after a power cycle of the modem:

```
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel            9,   5 Mar 16 11:18 cu.usbmodem123456781
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel            9,   4 Mar 16 11:18 tty.usbmodem123456781
```

Neither of those lines are present after a restart until the modem is
plugged in again.

What can I do programatically that will activate and detect the modem even after a restart?

Edit: the macOS System Report sees the USB device, before and after I unplug/replug:

[image]

Comment: If the modem doesn't appear under `/dev/cu....`, it basically a macOS and/or driver issue. You should probably the manufacturer re updated drivers. macOS Mojave used kernel mode drivers for serial devices. They are now deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Conexant is defunct and there is no driver update.  I think the drivers are manufacturer dependent, but macOS recognizes the device in the USB System Report. Because unplugging and re-plugging worked, I was hoping to use a tweak of some sort.  My fallback is a new modem.